# export generics in MEF

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, mef

I want to export a generic class to a generic interface via MEF. My objects are:

```
public interface IService<T> { }

[Export(typeof(IService<T>))] // error!!!!!!
public class Service<T> { }

public class Client<T> {
    [Import]
    private IService<T> _service;
}
```

But when I try to export `IService<T>`, I get this error:

> Attribute argument cannot use type parameters

Can anybody guide me to do this please?

Comment: By the way i would recommend to specify an interface like: `public class Service<T> where T : IMyInterface`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
[Export(typeof(IService<>))]
```

To get a generic type definition from the `typeof` operator, you omit type arguments.  For types with more than one type parameter, use commas to indicate the "arity" of the type.  For example:

```
typeof(List<>)              // not: typeof(List<T>)
typeof(IDictionary<,>)      // not: typeof(IDictionary<K, V>)
```