# Open Generic types won't register in the catalog

Tags: c#, mef

We're using .NET 4.5 and have had no problem with open generic exports in MEF up until a month ago when it suddenly stopped working. 70 tests on our CI server turned red and we traced it down to missing parts in the container.

I found it strange, so I wrote this test code:

```
var catalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(Impersonator<>), typeof(Cache<>));
var parts = catalog.Parts;
```

But it looks like none of the open generic types will register in the catalog.  `Parts` is a `TypeCatalog` with `Types = <Empty>`.

Usually we go about this by declarative exports using attributes as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295310/export-generics-in-mef), but none of the alternatives seems to be working anymore.

Any idea will be most appreciated.

Comment: This problem only seems to appear in unit tests. I created a console app and the problem went away. Trying the same in unit tests breaks. Here's the full test and research https://gist.github.com/miklund/6619891

Comment: I don't know if this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034777/mef-open-generic-problems-with-4-5 As well, did you guys install the .NET Framework 4.5.1 Preview or RC onto the CI server?

Comment: From my own testing it seems that with .NET 4.0 it doesn't work (in a console app) but 4.5 it does. It made me look around, and think perhaps http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~charlie.poole/nunit-vs-adapter/rc1/revision/60 has a role in this? Quite odd if it did, though.

Comment: How are you running the tests? I found that [`vstest.console.exe` defaults to `/Framework:Framework40`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796%28v=vs.140%29.aspx). It is still perfectly happy to load and execute .net-4.5 assemblies, even when they use APIs not available in .net-4.0. But MEF’s automatic open type closing feature is disabled when loaded by .net-4.5 running in .net-4.0 compatibility mode. So now I run my tests with `/Framework:Framework45` and everything works as expected ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Any idea what triggered it to start failing? Did you get a .NET update in that timeframe?

Out of curiosity if you write a simple console app targeting .NET 4.5 does this issue repro?

The reason I ask is I believe there was an update released for .NET 4.5 to make sure open generics didn't break existing .NET 4.0 apps and so if for some reason your tests are running in .NET 4.0 mode then then the open generic support will be disabled which could cause what you are seeing.

Comment: Cleared the issue by writing a few lines of work around code.  I'll try to reproduce the issue in a console app when I got time, and post it here.

Comment: I did create an console app trying to reproduce the issue and failed. So, it is something else in my code making MEF misbehave. I'll continue my search and update here if I come up with some answers.

Comment: @MikaelLundin Failing in unit tests but not in a console app sounds like the path I followed when discovering that `vstest.console.exe` defaults to running in .net-4.0 mode. Maybe I should just post that as an answer, heh.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this in my web app by putting the entry < httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /> in my web.config. For non-web apps, make sure the app.config has the entry 
        < supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />.

see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue, but I have some additional information that may help others.

I ran into the same issue.  My unit tests were working then suddenly stopped.  We narrowed it down to a pair of Windows updates: KB2840642v2 and KB2840642.  After uninstalling these, MEF started working properly again in unit tests.  I didn't see anything in the release notes for those updates that should affect things, but you know how that goes.

However, I am now running Windows 8 unfortunately, and the issue has popped up again.  I do not have those updates installed.  I think they were incorporated natively into the operating system.

Comment: Might not hurt to post these details on Microsoft Connect.

Answer (score 1):

When you say “on our CI server”, that does not tell us much about how you’re running the tests. However, I seem to get an experience like yours using `vstest.console.exe`.

I found a situation where MEF’s automatic open type closing feature, new in .net-4.5, will appear to break when running tests with `vstest.console.exe`. Basically, `vstest.console.exe` might decide to run in .net-4.0 compatibility mode as if `/Framework:Framework40` had been passed to it. .net-4.5 assemblies will load and run perfectly fine even when loaded by a .net-4.0 runtime, but MEF detects that you’re running in .net-4.0 mode and disables its support for automatically closing open generic types. You can get MEF to behave properly again by forcing `vstest.console.exe` to run in .net-4.5 mode by passing the `/Framework:Framework45` switch.

(This tested on a machine with .net-4.6.1 installed, though, not sure if that changes things yet more).

### Minimal Repro

When I make a simple test assembly targeting the .net-4.5 framework, `vstest.console.exe` correctly guesses that it should run the tests with .net-4.5. However, when I make an assembly that integrates into a more complex build environment, `vstest.console.exe` suddenly starts running in .net-4.0 mode rather than .net-4.5 mode. So I started with my complex build environment and started paring things down until the issue disappeared.

To get `vstest.console.exe` to guess the wrong framework, you need two assemblies. In one, define a custom assembly `Attribute`. In another, apply that custom assembly attribute and define your unit tests.

First assembly:

```
using System;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly)]
public class BreakVSTestFrameworkDetectionAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Second assembly referencing the prior one:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;

[assembly: BreakVSTestFrameworkDetection]

[InheritedExport]
public interface IGenericService<T>
{
    void Print(T thing);
}

public class SomeGenericService<T> : IGenericService<T>
{
    public void Print(T thing) => Console.WriteLine($"{typeof(T)}:{thing}");
}

[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Run()
    {
        using (var catalogue = new ApplicationCatalog())
        using (var container = new CompositionContainer(catalogue))
        {
            container.GetExportedValue<IGenericService<string>>().Print("asdf"); // System.String:asdf
            container.GetExportedValue<IGenericService<int>>().Print(123); // System.Int32:123
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args) => new UnitTest1().Run();
}
```

With these two assemblies and the defined test, I get the following outcomes in different scenarios:

1. Running the tests using Visual Studio 2015 Community Editions’s GUI works perfectly fine.

   [image: Test Explorer / MefGenericsUnitTests (1) / 1 Test Passed]
2. Running the code directly as an executable works fine.

   ```
   C:\Users\ohnob\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MefGenericsUnitTests>bin\Debug\MefGenericsUnitTests.exe
   System.String:asdf
   System.Int32:123
   ```
3. Running the tests with something like mstest ([except I can’t tell why one would or wouldn’t use this instead of vstest](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/7561/17216)) magically works (at least in this case) (output trimmed).

   ```
   C:\Users\ohnob\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MefGenericsUnitTests>"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" /testcontainer:bin\Debug\MefGenericsUnitTests.exe
   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.23107.0
   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

   Loading bin\Debug\MefGenericsUnitTests.exe...
   Starting execution...

   Results               Top Level Tests
   -------               ---------------
   Passed                UnitTest1.Run
   1/1 test(s) Passed
   ```
4. Running with straight up `vstest.console.exe` fails (output trimmed):

   ```
   C:\Users\ohnob\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MefGenericsUnitTests>"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" bin\Debug\MefGenericsUnitTests.exe
   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.24720.0
   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Starting test execution, please wait...
   Failed   Run
   Error Message:
      Test method UnitTest1.Run threw exception:
   System.ComponentModel.Composition.ImportCardinalityMismatchException: No exports were found that match the constraint:
           ContractName    IGenericService(System.String)
           RequiredTypeIdentity    IGenericService(System.String)
   ```
5. But `vstest.console.exe /Framework:Framework45` succeeds:

   ```
   C:\Users\ohnob\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MefGenericsUnitTests>"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" /Framework:Framework45 bin\Debug\MefGenericsUnitTests.exe
   Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.24720.0
   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Starting test execution, please wait...
   Passed   Run

   Total tests: 1. Passed: 1. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
   Test Run Successful.
   Test execution time: 3.7855 Seconds
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not use open generic and should provide a concrete running class like:

```
var catalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(Impersonator<type1>), typeof(Impersonator<type2>), typeof(Cache<type3>), typeof(Cache<type4>));
var parts = catalog.Parts;
```

I tried using interfaces like IImpersonator and ICache and does not work also:

```
interface IImpersonator { }
class Impersonator<T> : IImpersonator
...
var catalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(IImpersonator), typeof(ICache));
var parts = catalog.Parts;
```

Comment: As I've said above - it works fine when running at as an executable application, but not at all when running it in unit tests. I wonder if it has something to do with how test suits are executed.